# R foreach loop and AUGLAG?

Tags: r, optimization

I am using AUGLAG to find 100k points optimum points along a curve.  When I run the code without parallel processing it takes 1.7 days to run.  When I run the code below it takes only 2.5 minutes but it is only finding 1k points and then stopping.  Is there a problem when using AUGLAG within a a foreach() loop?

```
effHolder<-foreach(i=1:loops, .combine=rbind)%dopar%{
    target<-c((i-1)*increment)  #target CFaR
    sol <- auglag(pars, fn=fn, gr=NULL, heq=eqn, lower=lH, upper=uH, nl.info = FALSE, control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-8, maxeval = 20000))
    targetHolder<-target
    target<-0
    c(sol$par, targetHolder, eqn(sol$par), sol$value)
}
stopCluster(cl)

eff<-rbind(eff, effHolder)
```

Comment: Have you tried exporting it to the workers? (I don't even see that you loaded its library for that matter.) You really ought to stop capitalizing function names in R. It's a bad habit you perhaps picked up in SAS?

Comment: LOL, I may have picked that up in SAS.  I loaded, nloptr, ggplot2, scales, foreach and doSNOW at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'exporting it to the workers?'  Do I need to give nloptr to each worker?  How do I do that?

Comment: There is a `.packages` parameter. If you gave "nloptr" to that parameter, it would answer your question about availability of `auglag`. I would have guessed that a total failure should have been the result if that were the problem. I'm wondering if it's something to do with your `increment` variable that I do not see a value for.

Comment: Thank you BondedDust, you were right, I was not passing nloptr to the workers.  eff must have been outputting old data stored in my workspace or something.

Comment: Since it turned out to be the "answer" we might as well get it marked as such, since it might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a .packages parameter. If you gave "nloptr" to that parameter, it would answer your question about availability of auglag. I would have guessed that a total failure should have been the result if that were the problem.  So the code fragment would be:

```
foreach(i=1:loops, .combine=rbind, .packages="nloptr")%dopar%{
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too vague and not reproducible. That said, consider the following examples.

Foreach iterates over all of the specified iteration variables in parallel, so the loop is limited by the iteration variable with the fewest number of values.

It is limited by "j", returning one element:

```
 foreach(i=1:3, j=10,.combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    c(i, j)
  }
# [1]  1 10
```

This one is limited by "i", returning three elements.

```
  foreach(i=1:3, j=10:100, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
   c(i, j)
 }
         [,1] [,2]
# result.1    1   10
# result.2    2   11
# result.3    3   12
```

I hope this clears up your ideas.